# How to access Spring managed properties from bean's methods?

Tags: java, spring

I have list of properties mantianed in .properties file.
Now I am managing those property file wiht `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.

I want to access property value from one of the method.
Can anyone please suggest how to achieve that?

example

```
connection.properties
dev.url = "http://localhost:8080/"
uat.url = "http://xyz.com"
```

Now I have configured `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean by specifing connection.properties

I have one method which reads url based on mode of deployment 
so base on mode of deployment I want to change url using property file.

Please let me know if this is right approach.

If you have any suggestion please give.

Answer (score 3):

The `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` [does not expose](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) its properties . You could however easily read in the properties file anew using e.g. [`PropertiesLoadUtils`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PropertiesLoaderUtils.html):

```
PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(
        new ClassPathResource("/connection.properties"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're looking for something like the [@Value](http://chrislovecnm.com/2010/03/08/spring-3-java-based-configuration-with-value/) annotation?

```
private @Value("#{connection.dev.url}") String myURL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you are looking for, but I have utility where it loads properties based on environment its running on (dev,prod)

```
public class EnvironmentalPlaceHolderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
        implements InitializingBean {

    private Resource overrideLocation;

    public void setOverrideLocation(Resource overrideLocation) {
        this.overrideLocation = overrideLocation;
    }
    if(overrideLocation != null){
            if( overrideLocation.exists())
                super.setLocation(overrideLocation);
            else{
                logger.warn("Unbale to find "+overrideLocation.getFilename() +" using default");
            }
        }else{
            logger.warn("Override location not set, using default settings");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        setProperLocation();
    }
```

Then you need to define bean as

```
<bean class="com.commons.config.EnvironmentalPlaceHolderConfigurer">
    <property name="overrideLocation" value="classpath:/jms/${ENV_NAME}-jms.properties" />
    <property name="location" value="classpath:/jms/jms.properties" />
</bean>
```

You need to define a environment entry on machine with key as "ENV_NAME"

Ex:  ENV_NAME=prod

In case of windows environment variable and in case of unix entry in .profile.

You need to maintain properties for each environment in following fashion
prod-jms.properties
uat-jms.properties